# What's the valid term for a "base" for plants?

Tags: phrase-request, terminology

In case of some plants you can take their cuttings to multiply them. The cuttings are put in the ground directly, so you can have multiple seedlings based on one plant. You can have dozens of plants which are used for this process.

Boxwood or jasmine can both be a good example of such plant.

The term which describes such a group of plants in my language is "matecznik", which is a variation of the word mother.

What's the correct term for such a group of plants? I'm looking for the name of the group of the plants that other plants were grown from.

Edit: I found some book titles that might be close to it:

> Schoeneweiss D.F. 1969. Susceptibility of evergreen hosts to the
>   juniper blight fungus, Phomopsis juniperovora, under epidemic
>   conditions. J. Am. Soc. Hortic. Sci. 94(6): 609-611.
>
> Remlein-Starosta D. 2004. Pestalotiopsis associated with Erica spp
>   ornamental plants in nurseries near Poznań- increasing problem.

Is an evergreen host or nursery a correct term for it?

Comment: Are you talking about [*grafting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting), or something else?

Comment: Something else - the cuttings are put in the ground directly, so you can have multiple seedlings based on one plant. The group of the plants which are used for it is called a "motherbase" in my language.

Comment: Could you give some examples of plants that are like this? Are potatoes like this? (just a guess) Also, what is the word in your language?

Comment: @DJ - I think the O.P. is referring to [this](http://content.ces.ncsu.edu/plant-propagation-by-stem-cuttings-instructions-for-the-home-gardener/). (Please, emilos, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: J.R., that's exactly it. @DJMcMayhem boxwood and jasmine are good examples of such plants. The word is "matecznik", which is a variation of the word "mother"

Comment: Are you looking for the name of the *group* of plants, or the *single* plant the rest of the group was grown from?

Comment: @cpast I'm looking for the name of the group of plants that the rest of the plants were grown from.

Comment: Not that this question is off-topic (It's definitely a good question for this site), but you might be able to get a better answer on Gardening. Or maybe even on Biology. (although Gardening is probably a better bet)

Comment: @DJMcMayhem thanks, that's a good idea, I didn't know that Gardening exists as a separate site. I'll try my luck over there too.

Comment: @emilos haha, I didn't either. I just suspected that there might be so I looked for one. That's one of the things I love about SE, there's a site for everything!

Comment: I'm gonna guess "parent stock", but I'm not a gardener.

Comment: I think it's [multiplying plants by root cuttings](http://www.ehow.com/how_7102743_root-placing-glass-bottle-water.html).

Answer (score 7):

You are referfing to the process of [vegetative reproduction](http://botanydictionary.org/vegetative-reproduction.html) where

> specialized multicellular organs formed by the **parent** become detached and generate new individuals

The process can occur naturally, or it can be done by humans e.g. in horticulture (than the process is also called [vegetative propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetative_reproduction). The parent is also called **parent plant**. In natural vegetative reproduction (e.g. in strawberries) it can be also called **main plant**. The group of plants that originated from a **parent plant** and persist in nature in a certain area over a period of time is known as a **clonal colony**.

[image]

Ref: Dictionary of Botany, Wikipedia and [TutorVista](http://www.tutorvista.com/content/biology/biology-ii/reproduction/asexual-reproductions.php)

P.S. It is definitely not *evergreen host* - [evergreen](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/evergreen_2) are plants that don't shed their leaves in winter and *host* reffers to a plant infected with fungus - it suggests a host-parasite relationship. [Nursery](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/nursery) refers to a place where plants are being grown and sold. (Definitions adapted from LDOCE)

Answer (score 2):

@Lucky's answer contains the formal terminology, *vegetative propagation*.

Informally this process is called [*cloning*](http://sdhydroponics.com/resources/articles/gardening/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-cloning-plants) and the cuttings are referred to as *clones*. The plant the clones come from  is called the *parent*. If male, it can be referred to as the *father*, if female, as the *mother*.